# Javascript getTime to php date

Tags: php, javascript, date, gettime

I have javascript that turns dates in my view to a time string using getTime(). That then is stored as a value for an option in my select form. Once it is passed to php, how do I turn that into a php date?

I have done:

```
echo date("m/d/Y", '1345618799000');

1345618799000 = Tue Aug 21 2012
```

Answer (score 9, accepted):

You use PHP's [date()](http://php.net/manual/en/function.date.php) function:

```
date("Format here (see documentation)", round($_POST["time_field"]/1000));
```

Updated, thanks Yoshi.

Comment: that's what i did but its off by a lot

Comment: @chris What did you use for format? Also, if you did try something first (which is something nearly everyone here requires for a question) add it to the question.

Comment: @chris That's expectable as js' `getTime` includes milliseconds, while `date` does not expect them. Try dividing the timestamp by 1000 first.

Comment: echo date("m/d/Y", '134630999900');

Comment: +1 ;) though the obvious error checking on `$_POST["time_field"]` should not be forgotten in production code.

Answer (score 0):

You may use PHP's `strtotime()` to change any string into a Unix timestamp;
[strtotime()](http://www.w3schools.com/php/func_date_strtotime.asp)